# Visual C++:error C2664: 'ReleaseDC' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'HDC' to 'HWND'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I want to compile [an old (1998) implementation of Edge Collapse from Game Developer's Magazine](http://www.gdmag.com/src/nov98.zip) (Project file is compressed in "melax.zip") on Visual Studio 2008.

On line 390 of winmain.cpp I get the following compile error:

```
winmain.cpp(390) : error C2664: 'ReleaseDC' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'HDC' to 'HWND'
```

and again in line 439.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Answer removed, the relevant code was not posted so we were supposed to guess (yes, you linked to a zip, but simply posting line 390 would have expedited the solution)

Comment: It's too long. I included the link to it on gdmag, themel used it and saw the fault. It's kinda impressive to see it run.

Comment: line 390 is too long to post? now I really want to see it, but still, not enough to download it.

Comment: @omgzor "It's kinda impressive to see it *compile*".  There fixed that for ya.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Yeah, sorry, I had cramps on my hands *just* at that moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arguments to `ReleaseDC` are reversed in the call - he calls `ReleaseDC(hDC, hWnd)`, while the [correct signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is

```
int ReleaseDC(
  __in  HWND hWnd,
  __in  HDC hDC
);
```

Enjoy fixing a 13 year old bug :)

Answer (score 2):

The said line looks like this:

```
ReleaseDC(hDC, hWnd);
```

However, the function [`ReleaseDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) accepts parameters in the backwards order.